# Delete all objects from database in hibernate Spring java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oracle11g

I want to delete all those rows from **xyz** table where id = 1 using hibernate spring.

I have tried following code but its not giving error but not deleting rows -

```
 Session session = (Session) getEm().getDelegate();
 String sql ="Delete from xyz where id=:id" ;
SQLQuery query  = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("id", "1");
int flg = query.executeUpdate();
```

Can you please help me to delete all rows using hibernate query.

Comment: What is the value of flg?

Comment: It equals to the total no of counts in database.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code within a transaction like this:

```
Session session = (Session) getEm().getDelegate();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
String sql ="Delete from xyz where id=:id" ;
SQLQuery query  = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("id", "1");
int flg = query.executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
query.setParameter("id", Long.valueOf(1));
```

if your entity is of type Long (which ideally should be).

Reference: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-basics-3-ways-to-delete-an-entity-from-the-datastore

Note: The link is just for your reference.

Comment: Your "xyz" in your delete query should be the class name in case you are unaware.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void deleteById(Class clazz,Integer id) {
    String hql = "delete " + clazz.getName() + " where id = :id";
    Query q = session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("id", id);
    q.executeUpdate();
}
```